# Show AVG in HH:MM:SS:FFF

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression, bids

I'm trying to replicate this SQL code in BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008)

`CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(MS,ROUND(AVG(CAST(MYSECONDFIELD AS DECIMAL)*1000), 2),'00:00:00')) [HH:MM:SS:FFF]`

So far I've got the below;

`=FORMAT(DATEADD("MS",ROUND(AVG(CDec(Fields!MySecondField.Value))*1000,2),"00:00:00:000"), "HH:mm:ss:fff")`

However it seems to error out at the DATEADD function and it must be in BIDS but I can format the field in SQL, I'm wondering if there an easier way to do this,

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? And why are you applying avg on single value ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? And why are you applying avg on single value ? And why do you want to add your miliseconds ? And SSRS doesn't supports Milliseconds that needs to be converted into the seconds.

Comment: If SSRS doesn't support Milliseconds in the DATEADD function, do you know a way that i can get an AVERAGE to display in HH:MM:SS:FFF format? The formula is used in a grouping so either Hour,Day,Month etc so its not averaging a single field.